# getting Firebase Cloud messaging running swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am following Google's instructions on setting up Firebase https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html
I suspect the problem may be because the help is for the legacy version. However deprecated should not read an error, at least I have found this for apple deprecations. The following code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")
    // Write data to Firebase
    myRootRef.setValue("Do you have data? You'll love Firebase.")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

gives the following error

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<Firebase>'
```

From the link, this is the exact same code prescribed. I have installed pods for Firebase and Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Take a look on [the new docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start); maybe could help

Comment: I've given those a go. They don't provide step-by-step instructions like the legacy docs do and I'm not sure how to fill in the steps in between. Trying to find resources on this topic has proved to be fruitless

Comment: There are no in between steps.  The new steps are different, hence the need for new instructions.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial that works. Its by google so its up to date with the new Firebase.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#0

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'module'

The error is saying that you imported a module named `Firebase` here:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
```

And then you tried calling the module as if it's a function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var myRootRef = Firebase(...)
```

I think the old Firebase module must have defined a function/class called Firebase, so that when you imported the old Firebase module, that made the Firebase() function/initializer available.  Apparently, the new Firebase module doesn't define that function/class anymore, hence the need for the new instructions.

In addition, your url can't be correct:

```
url:"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com"
```

You would substitute the actual name of your app in place of `<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>`.

In any case, you don't specify a url in your code anymore: instead you call `FIRApp.configure()` in AppDelegate.swift, and that takes care of connecting to the proper url for you.  How does `configure(`) know which url to connect to? Look in the GoogleService-Info.plist file that you dragged into your app--you’ll see the db url in there.

To get a reference to the top of your db, all you do is:

```
dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

Here it is in a ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        dbRef.child("person").child("name").setValue("Joe")
```

After running your app, you'll see something like the following at the Firebase website:

```
abcd-1234
 |____person
        |__name: “Joe”
```